# Serialize JSON Object received that has data type 'LocalDateTime'

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a class Dto that will set a value with `LocalDateTime` as Data Type.

I get an error when receiving a JSON.

```
public class Dto {

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDateTime scheduledStartTime;

}
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Cannot construct instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('2019-08-01T15:30:00Z')
```

Answer (score 0):

try disabling :

```
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
```

or

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
```

Comment: During receiving the JSON in the DTO or during sending the JSON?

Comment: Im new to Serialization/Deserialization